# Getting Python to round Timestamp with NS versus Truncate

Tags: python

Tried a couple different methods and both didn't return my desired result. I'm trying to get .349566 to show in my microseconds decimal place versus the .349565 that is currently showing, as I want it to round versus truncate.

```
In [113]: dateutil.parser.parse('2014-06-18 13:06:00.349565827')
Out[113]: datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 18, 13, 6, 0, 349565)

(Pandas)
In [114]: pd.Timestamp('2014-06-18 13:06:00.349565827')
Out[114]: Timestamp('2014-06-18 13:06:00.349565', tz=None)
```

Thoughts on a quick way to do this? I know of a lot of options using string manipulation and such but that is obviously not my goal.

Comment: I don't think there is any way without manipulating the string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to round it manually, unfortunately. On the plus side, that's relatively easy to do in your use case. String formatting for floats can round natively, so that's probably how I'd go about it:

```
date_str = '2014-06-18 13:06:00.349565827'

# split off the seconds & microseconds
beginning, sec = date_str.rsplit(':', 1) 

# Use string formatting to recreate a rounded timestamp
date = dateutil.parser.parse('{}:{:02.6f}'.format(beginning, float(sec)))
```

Comment: This does run, it gives `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I'd added an extra decimal point by mistake. It's fixed now.

Comment: Hey, what about on something like this: date_str = '20140618 19:16:38.73754749' -- the output is showing 737547, when rounded correctly it would be 737548.

Comment: @user1610719 I don't know of *any* built-in rounding function (in Python or otherwise) that performs tail-first rounding like that. If you want that behavior you'll have to implement it yourself.